# Error in using XBee python library in raspberry Pi3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, xbee

I want to use XBee python library in raspberry pi. when I run the code, I encounter the following Error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "XBeeMQTT-V1.py", line 25, in <module>
       from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
       File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/digi/xbee/devices.py", line 22, in <module>
       File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/digi/xbee/serial.py", line 15, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name Serial
```

I import serial and xbee-digi in the python code and install both library on raspberry pi (usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages). 
have any idea where the error stems from?

Comment: install pyserial

Comment: I did it. In usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages I have folder serial. this is what you mean?

running the command pip install pyserial, I got this message:


          Requirement already satisfied: pyserial in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
          You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
         You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: You must not create the folder, you must install pyserial

Comment: execute `sudo apt-get install python-serial`

Comment: after running the cmd (sudo apt-get install python-serial), I got the same error as previous

Comment: Well then report it as a bug. :)

Comment: In the documentation of the library, it is mentioned that it need python 3. but the library installed on python 2.7, Do you think it may cause the problem? and if so, how to solve it.

Comment: Then install for python 3:  `sudo apt-get install python3-pip && sudo apt-get install python3-serial && sudo pip install xbee-digi`

Comment: when I run the cmd

          sudo pip3 install xbee-digi

got

         Collecting xbee-digi
        Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xbee-digi (from versions: )
        No matching distribution found for xbee-digi

Comment: excuse me, execute `sudo pip3 install digi-xbee`

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, follow the steps:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip && sudo apt-get install python3-serial
```

then go to */usr/local/lib/python3.x/dist-packages*   and run

```
sudo pip3 install setuptools
```

and finally

```
sudo pip3 install digi-xbee
```